# Google analytics setup for Facebook account?

Tags: google-analytics

but don't have a website. I want use Google Analytics for Facebook. Can we use Google Analytics only for Facebook?

Comment: i think facebook gives you a lot of information like google analytics.

Comment: No, you cannot put Google Analytics on a Facebook Page. You're stuck with what Facebook provides in your Page's analytics. https://www.facebook.com/analytics/

Answer (score 0):

No, to use Google Analytics you have to be able to alter the code of the app you want to analyze. Since you can't alter the code of a Facebook page, you can't apply Google Analytics to it. Facebook provides analytics, though. https://www.facebook.com/analytics/